# spring aop expression for subpackages

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I've written spring aop expression around type like

```
@Around("execution(* com.mycomp.proj.parent.child1.*.*(..))
|| execution(* com.mycomp.proj.parent.child2.*.*(..))")
```

But this expression won't be applied for new packages if they will be created under the parent `(e.g.:com.mycomp.proj.parent.child3`). How to develop expression which include this point and doesn't be applied for classes which are located directly in the parent package? (Just expression which is able to apply only for classes from all sub packages)

Answer (score 1):

exclude the parent:

```
@Around("execution(* com.mycomp.proj.parent.*.*(..))
&& ! execution(* com.mycomp.proj.parent.*(..))")
```

Comment: It doesn't work. So, it throws exception while it tries to setup context: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.mycomp.proj.parent [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]"

Answer (score 1):

Apply an extra period as below

```
@Around("execution(* com.mycomp.proj.parent..*.*(..))")
```

It will allow pointcut on all subpackages of com.mycomp.proj.parent

Answer (score 0):

@Around("execution(* com.mycomp.proj.parent.child1.*.*(..))
|| execution(* com.mycomp.proj.parent.child2.*.*(..))")